# Using google reflections to load resource files

Tags: reflections

I am working on a JavaFX project and I my project structure is as follows.

[This is my Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWsfa.png)

I want to load `*fxml` files under `/src/main/java/resources/view/primary` in `/src/main/java/windchimes.ui/WindChimesApplication.java` using Google Refletions. I tried using following code for it

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("windchimes.ui",new ResourcesScanner());
Set<String> scenePaths = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*fxml"));
```

When I run the above code snippet, java throws the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
>     at
>   org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.(JavassistAdapter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder.(ConfigurationBuilder.java:41)
>     at org.reflections.Reflections$1.(Reflections.java:134)   at
>   org.reflections.Reflections.(Reflections.java:134)  at
>   org.reflections.Reflections.(Reflections.java:117)  at
>   windchimes.ui.WindChimesApplication.(WindChimesApplication.java:27)
>     ... 10 more

I am sure that I am not creating the Reflection object according to my use case. Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the package prefix and also I believe you are looking for .fxml files. This code should work. Can you try it out?

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("windchimes.ui")));
    Set<String> res = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.fxml"));
```